# How to fix "PAYEE_NOT_CONSENTED" error when capture the order in paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I created developer account and created some test sandbox accounts.
And I created REST API app. Using the client_id and client_secret of this app, I created order. I set payee in order request like the following:

```
$response = self::$guzzleClient->post(
  "/v2/checkout/orders",
  [
    'headers' => [
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'Accept'     => 'application/json',
      'Authorization' => "Bearer $accessToken"
    ],
    'json' => [
      'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
      'purchase_units' => [
        [
          'amount' => [
            'value' => 100,
            'currency_code' => 'EUR',
          ],
          'payee' => [
            'email_address' => "test@example.com"
          ]
        ]
      ],
      'payment_source' => [
        "paypal" => [
          "experience_context" => [
            "payment_method_preference" => "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED",
            "payment_method_selected" => "PAYPAL",
            "locale" => "de-DE",
            "landing_page" => "LOGIN",
            "shipping_preference" => "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
            "user_action" => "PAY_NOW",
            "return_url" => "https://www.paypal.com",
            "cancel_url" => "https://www.paypal.com"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
);
```

I am now developing web application for doctors.
After the treatment, patients should pay invoice to the doctor's account, not hospital's account. So I should set payee. Am I right?
But "PAYEE_NOT_CONSENTED" error shows me when I capture the order after creating order.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set a payee -- but for permission to facilitate payments on their behalf first onboard them to your platform using the [partner referrals API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/before-payment/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you provide me sample code using REST API?

Comment: The documentation has samples, along with other information necessary for being approved to use the API